# Generate a 5-pointed star

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

Your challenge is generate a [5 pointed star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-pointed_star) like below. The star doesn't need to be filled.
Shortest code wins.

[image]

Comment: Your image shows a [Five-pointed-star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-pointed_star), a pentagram has the connecting lines.

Comment: "Don't need to be filled" means that it can be filled? And, how are we defining "filled"? In the case of a pentagram, as Johannes has mentioned, there would normally be lines on the inside which create a pentagon across the inside-facing points. Would that qualify, or is an answer only valid if the star is either completely filled or a perfect outline?

Comment: @Iszi Looks like shortest question wins.

Comment: wingdings, 1: « (character 0xAB), or unicode: Pentagram: ⛤ U+26E4 &#9956; New in Unicode 6

Comment: @SeanC Forbidden loopholes. Graphics using unicode is forbidden by default.

Comment: @SIGSEGV, challenge doesn't exclude standard loopholes

Comment: @SeanC They're *standard*. That means you don't have to specifically state they are disallowed.

Comment: Love how the top voted answer is a Unicode star, but mines invalid due to floating point limitations of graphics in Java ._.

Comment: @mbomb007, but the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) were not discussed until after this question was asked:  First edit: asked Feb 22 '14 at 23:30

Comment: So? Meta discussions are often applied retroactively. The entire site is held to the same standards and cleaned up after the fact, rather than only new questions having to abide by new rules. This is because old questions can always be answered later.

Comment: @mbomb007, so I should now delete comments that were valid at the time, but now don't conform?

Comment: If you see them, yeah. We do that for questions already.

Comment: @mathe Is outputting the unicode character allowed?

Comment: @SIGSEGV There is no loophole for that in the standard loopholes thread.

Answer (score 30):

## PHP, 1 character

Although very short it will probably not become the accepted answer.

```
☆
```

(this is U+2606). May work also in other languages (untested).

Comment: interestingly, my JRuby console and my phone render this as a real five-pointed star, but my Chrome/Win7 renders this as an ordinary (five-pointed) asterisk, which is filled and nowhere as straight-edged as the star it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Jan I get the correct star on chrome/win7 *and* my android phone

Comment: oh, wait, I do get a real star, but it's so small it looks a bit like an asterisk. Never mind...

Comment: This is 2 bytes, is it not?

Comment: Also, this answer is invalid, because the challenge is [graphical-output], not [ascii-art].

Comment: @mbomb007 Character glyphs are hardly ASCII art.

Comment: So it's unicode. Either way, it's not valid.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm not nitpicking because you said *ASCII*. ASCII art uses several characters to resemble a shape; this is different. Provided that a proper font is used, this prints the desired output in a terminal or a web browser, so I fail to see why it would be invalid.

Comment: Because that's not in the spirit of the challenge. If every answer used `print"☆"` or some variant because it's the shortest, this wouldn't be a challenge.

Comment: @mbomb007 That's a flaw of the challenge, not the answer.

Answer (score 20):

### LOGO, <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
REPEAT 5[FW 9LT 144FW 9RT 72]
```

[Run at logo.twentygototen.org](http://logo.twentygototen.org/vaZj5FJG)

Comment: Actually you don't need spaces *after* the numbers (3 chars)

Comment: @Howard: thanks for the tip.

Comment: Can be shorter if you make the pentagram defined in the OP's link: `REPEAT 5[FW 9LT 144]`

Answer (score 18):

## VBA PowerPoint, 92 bytes

```
Sub s()
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape msoShape5pointStar, 0, 0, 99, 99
End Sub
```

Because everything looks better in PowerPoint:

[image]

Comment: If you convert this to an immediates window function, convert `msoShape5pointStar` to its constant value (`92`) and remove the whitespace between the commas and values (`ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape 92,0,0,99,99`) you can condense the byte count to `57` bytes

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, <s>19</s> 18 bytes

This is easy, using `CirculantGraph`.

I drew a pentagram as defined in the link the OP used.

```
5~CirculantGraph~2
```

[image: pentagram]

---

A slightly longer way, but equally straightforward, is to use the curated "Lamina" entity. This returns a filled pentagram.

```
 "FilledPentagram"~LaminaData~"Image"
```

or

```
 EntityValue[Entity["Lamina","FilledPentagram"],"Image"]
```

---

[image: star]

Comment: Is the space actually necessary? I don't speak Mathematica, but I know many other languages would be forgiving of omitting the space in a circumstance such as this.

Comment: No, the space is not necessary. That's why I didn't count the space. Just about the only time space matters is inside a string and in the case of implicit multiplication (e.g. 3 5 == 15). "==" is equals in Mathematica.

Comment: One char less `5~CirculantGraph~2`

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3, 137 bytes

Polar plot.

```
import pylab as P,numpy as N
S=N.sin
p=N.pi
a=.9*p
d=8e-4*p
A=lambda t:N.arange(0,t,d)
P.polar(A(4*p),list(S(a)/S(a-A(.8*p)))*5)
P.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `import pylab as P,math as M;α=[4*M.pi*i/5for i in range(6)];A=[1]*6;P.polar(α,A);P.show()` (89 chars) paints similar figure

Comment: @AMK nice, I see the trick. You could write it as a new answer.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters are not a single byte. Edited to make ASCII-only in order for the byte count to be correct.

Answer (score 8):

## Small Basic, 50 bytes

```
For i=1To 5
Turtle.Move(9)
Turtle.Turn(144)
EndFor
```

A verbose language, but it has built in turtle functionality. Slowly draws a very, very tiny pentagram.

[image: very tiny pentagram.]

Answer (score 7):

## HTML & CSS: <s>270</s> 269 bytes

```html
<p id=a/><p id=b></p><p id=c></p><p id=d></p><p id=e></p><style>p{position:absolute;width:300px;border-top:solid #000;margin:100px;transform-origin:50% 1666%}#b{transform:rotate(72deg)}#c{transform:rotate(144deg)}#d{transform:rotate(216deg)}#e{transform:rotate(288deg)}
```

Sample run:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fm6Hu/2/ (Explorer, Firefox, Opera)
- http://jsfiddle.net/fm6Hu/3/ (Chrome, Opera)

### HTML & CSS: 139 bytes

Impressing rewrite by [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

```css
div{height:20px;width:300px;border-bottom:solid #000;margin:100px;transform-origin:33% 5%;transform:rotate(72deg)}
```

```html
<div><div><div><div><div>
```

(Since first posted, all desktope browsers dropped vendor prefixes, so now one CSS code fits all.)

Comment: I just get a single horizontal line... Chrome 31.0.1650.57 on Win7

Comment: never mind, adding the `-webkit-` vendor prefix to `transform-origin` and `transform` fixed it. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fm6Hu/1/)

Comment: How do you do your syntax highlighting?

Comment: @lszi, not me, its [Google Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/). I just give it the language hint by adding a special HTML comment in front of the code block. See [Syntax highlighting for code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Thank you, @Doorknob. I had the feeling that now all browsers support transformations without vendor prefixes. Anyway, the previous concept failed in Opera, the new one is more portable.

Comment: You can save a bunch of bytes by nesting your tags. I came up with `<div><div><div><div><div>` and `div{height:20px;width:300px;border-bottom:solid #000;margin:100px;transform-origin:33% 5%;transform:rotate(72deg)}` just through trial and error.

Comment: Wow, that's huge, @Neil. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

## [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu), 4-6 blocks (52-79 scratchblocks code)

[image: flagclearpendownrep5(move100turncw144)] 
This produces this 
[image: starbycat]
If anyone's interested, [here's](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/83473614/) the project.
EDIT: To golf it, remove the pen down. You could remove the then flag clicked, too but it would only run if you clicked it. To golf the scratch blocks version, change "100" to "1", although you get a microscopic pentagram.

Nongolfed scratchblocks:

```
when gf clicked
clear
pen down
repeat (5
move (100) steps
turn cw (144) degrees
```

Comment: If I was to be pedantic, I'd count the bytes of each block. Interesting choice, though.

Comment: Consensus on meta is that Scratch answers be scored by the length of the corresponding `scratchblocks` code.

Comment: @ev3commander: I wouldn't consider that question to be proper competitive code golf

Answer (score 6):

## HTML5, 37 bytes

```
<svg><path d="M4,0 7,8 0,3 8,3 1,8"/>
```

Comment: HTML5, am I right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/790yyta6/

Answer (score 4):

### Tcl/Tk, 57 bytes

```
pack [canvas .c]
.c cr po 72 0 114 130 3 49 140 49 29 130
```

Comment: This actually draws a pentagram, but you don't see the connecting lines because it is filled with black.

Comment: I feel like by that logic you could paint the whole canvas black, and say: "This paints the pentagram, but it's the same colour as the background". So long as we only care about the output in determining correctness, these are indistinguishable(painting the whole canvas vs. painting black pentagram on a black canvas).

Comment: @Cruncher `the star don't need filled` -> but I can fill it. And the question asked for a pentagram, so I draw a filled pentagram that looks like the one in the question, only filled.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby with [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), 36 bytes

```
Shoes.app{star(points:5).move 99,99}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What would happen if you used a smaller number like 9 instead of 99?

Comment: @Cruncher The star would be off-screen and you would not be able to see it.

Comment: Interesting concept. I should learn it.

Comment: Is this valid? It's unclear what the angles have to be, but it doesn't match the image in the question.

Answer (score 4):

## [TurtleGolf](https://gist.github.com/DJgamer98/4702b11511ad4b1c2be5), <strike>70</strike> <strike>24</strike> 22 bytes

Note: This is non-competing, as this language was made after this challenge was posted (though specifically for this challenge).

```
0;
aa*^aa*4b*+>1+:5=?;
```

Explaination:

```
0; - Initialize the loop counter and go to the next line.
aa* - Get the value 100
^ - Move forward by 100px
aa*4b*+ - Get the value 144
> - Rotate 144 degrees to the right
1+ - Increment the loop counter by 1
: - Duplicate it cause we need a copy of it.
5= - Check if the loop counter equals 5, push 1 if it is.
?; - If the top of the stack equals 1, terminate the line.
```

#### Old, loopless version.

`aa*^aa*4a*+4+>aa*^aa*4a*+4+>aa*^aa*4a*+4+>aa*^aa*4a*+4+>aa*^aa*4a*+4+>`

<strike>I didn't add loops yet, so the code is kind of repetitive right now.</strike>

Explaination

```
aa*^              Move aa*(100) pixels forward
aa*4a*+a+         Get the value 144
>                 Turn 144 pixels to the right
```

EDIT: Shaved off lots of bytes.
EDIT2: Shaved off two more bytes.

Comment: Can't wait for loops!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I just added them :) Every single line is now a loop that executes until a ; is reached.

Comment: What is the behaviour when the stack is _not_ one? It just loops back to the beginning of the line?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ If the stack is exactly zero when you pass a zero, it skips the next instruction. It loops back to the beginning if there isnt any instruction to skip and skips the first instruction instead.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ When you pass a ?, not when you pass a zero. Sorry.

Comment: Ahhh thanks! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (msvc)], 88 bytes

```cpp
#include<Windows.h>
main(){int p[]={50,1,20,91,97,35,2,35,79,91};Polygon(GetDC(0),p,5);}
```

Answer (score 3):

### PostScript, 27 bytes

```
$ hexdump -C pentagram_binary.ps 
00000000  39 20 39 92 ad 30 20 39  92 6b 36 7b 30 20 39 92  |9 9..0 9.k6{0 9.|
00000010  63 31 34 34 92 88 7d 92  83 92 a7                 |c144..}....|
0000001b
```

[Download to try](http://www.mediafire.com/view/bovx5co194fswbn/pentagram_binary.ps).

Output:

[image: Pentagram rendered by Ghostscript]

Un-golfed ASCII version:

```
9 9 translate
0 9 moveto
6{
  0 9 lineto
  144 rotate
}repeat
stroke
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com), 46 characters

```
r=\sec\left(.4\arccos\left(\cos2.5\theta\right)\right)
```

Here is a longer version that allows you to choose some `n`:

```
r=\sec\left(\frac{2}{n}\arccos\left(\cos\frac{n\theta}{2}\right)\right)
```

Comment: Does this work the same way as the octave answer?

Comment: @GenericDisplayName Frankly, I have no idea. Probably, yeah, they both use polar things

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 47 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
for i in[144]*5:fd(i);rt(i)
```

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/16f9d37467)

The following (**42 bytes**) also works (Python 2 only), but Trinket doesn't allow `exec`, so you can't run it online. Also, the result is much smaller.

```python
from turtle import*
exec'fd(9);rt(144);'*5
```

Answer (score 2):

## Shell, 60 bytes

(Coordinates shamelessly stolen from [user1455003](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8055/user1455003)'s [SVG answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15603). For artistic merits upvote his answer.)

```sh
convert -size 9x9 xc: -draw 'polygon 4,0 7,8 0,3 8,3 1,8' x:
```

Sample output:

[image: pentagram]

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>50</s> 54 bytes

```
plot(1:9,t="n",as=1);polygon(c(5,8,1,9,2),c(1,9,4,4,9))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is not symmetrical?

Comment: @freekvd it's just a problem of aspect ratio. See edit

Answer (score 2):

## [Google Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/), 3 blocks

In response to the [Scratch answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61230/41257)

Blockly turtle doesn't need "so much" boilerplate code.

[image: Pentagram code]

This "code" can be ran [here](https://blockly-games.appspot.com/turtle?lang=en&level=3#da57w2) and produces this pentagram

[image: Pentagram output]

## Five pointed star, 5 blocks

The five pointed star can be tested [here](https://blockly-games.appspot.com/turtle?lang=en&level=1#vm6r6v)

[image: Five pointed star code][image: Five pointed star output]

Comment: Well, I didn't need "so much" code either, if you remove the flag block then it runs if you click it. Also, after the initialization, you wouldn't need "pen down", but whatever.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 40 bytes

```
symbols(1,st=cbind(8,3,8,3,8,3,8,3,8,3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, <s>394</s> 370 bytes

```
import UIKit
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:2,height:2),false,100)
let c1=0.3,c2=0.8,s1=1.0,s2=0.6,o=(0.0,1.0),p=[o,(s2,-c2),(-s1,c1),(s1,c1),(-s2,-c2),o].map{CGPoint(    x:$0.0,y:$0.1)},c=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
c.translateBy(x:1,y:1)
c.setLineWidth(1/100)
c.move(to:p[0])
p.forEach{c.addLine(to:$0)}
c.fillPath()
UIImage(cgImage:c.makeImage()!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 24 bytes

```
polar(t=[1:.8:5]*pi,~~t)
```

Output:

[image]

Or, for 36 bytes you can have just the outline:

```
polar(t=[0:.2:2]*pi,1-mod(t,pi/2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative without `polar` (but same length) would be `plot(e.^(i*pi*[0:.8:4]))`

Comment: @flawr Yes it would! I was actually working on the second plot first and couldn't figure out a good way to generate the `rho` vector, so the first plot here is really just a chopped down version of the second.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>37</s></sub> 35 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediates window function that takes no input and outputs a five pointed star to the top left of the `Sheet1` (default sheet) object

```vba
Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape 92,0,0,99,99
```

### Sample Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Tikz, <s>126</s> <s>120</s> 125 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to [Julian Wolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66904/julian-wolf)*

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usetikzlibrary{shapes}\begin{document}\tikz{\node[draw=red,star]{};}\end{document}
```

This draws a red star shaped node at `(0,0)`.

Comment: I think `\node` can be substituted for `\draw node` to save a few bytes

Comment: Make it 110:
`\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\usetikzlibrary{shapes}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz\node[draw=red,star]{};\end~` Nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 52 bytes

```
from turtle import*;exec('fd(99);rt(144);'*5);done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## JavaFX / FXML, 138 bytes

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?><?import javafx.scene.shape.*?><Pane><children><SVGPath content="M4,0 7,8 0,3 8,3 1,8"/></children></Pane>
```

I haven't tested it yet, though

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>

<Pane>
   <children>
      <SVGPath content="M4,0 7,8 0,3 8,3 1,8" stroke="BLACK"/>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/) + Pylab, 48-byte copout answer

```
from pylab import*
plot(0,0,marker=(5,1))
show()
```

Plots a single point using a five-pointed star as a marker.

Answer (score -1):

## TI-83/84 Basic, 32 bytes

```
Line(0,1,1,1:Line(0,0,.5,1.5:Line(1,0,.5,1.5
```

Note I haven't actually tested this out but I'm assuming it's going to show up as a low resolution, distorted star-shaped object.

- [Line(](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/line) command is one byte

Comment: You don't have to count the three instances of `:`, so your character count would be 42.

Comment: Thanks for updating me on this @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ since then we have agreed that TI-Basic is counted in bytes not chars anyway.

Comment: -1; this prints a barely-visible A-shaped figure, not a star.